# JQuery UI AutoComplete Implementation not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css, autocomplete

I am trying to implement the autocomplete provided with JQuery UI and I was wondering how I could do this by putting the source code provided:

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
```

into my script.js file.  In my .html file i have:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

where script.js is my .js file.  I have tried putting this in my .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
       source: availableTags
    });
});
```

and this in my .html file:

```
<form class="ui-widget" name="phoneForm">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags" name="phoneItem" placeholder="Add a Phone"/>
</form>
```

but this doesn't work.  Can anyone help me out as to what I am doing wrong and point me in the write direction?  Thanks!

Comment: check your browser console for any errors

Comment: Have you included jquery and jquery ui scripts?

Comment: @skukx This is what I included:

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src"script.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: You need to put your js <script> tag after the jquery script tags.  The file is loaded top down.  So when your javascript is loaded first it doesn't know jquery exists.  Put script.js after jquery script tags

Comment: Thanks, I changed it and it still isn't working.  I updated my post to show what I included.  Any more thoughts would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Are you including jQuery twice? It seems like you include both the minified and normal versions.

Comment: @powerbuoy hmm, are you saying if I include:         <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
I shouldn't include:         <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
?

Comment: Also, do I need to download the JQuery UI package or can I just use the google provided one online?

Comment: @bagelboy yes, that's correct. You don't need both. Regarding UI, you should be able to link directly to Google.

Answer (score 3):

Have You Tried this :

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var availableTags = [
                "United States",
                "France",
                "Germany",
                "China",
                "Australia",
                "England",
                "Saouth Korea",
                "India"
            ];
            $("#tags").autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags" placeholder="Enter Some Text…">
</body>

</html>
```

you can try demo here :
[demo](http://tutorialsplane.com/jquery-ui-autocomplete-demo/)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing quotes around the closing  tag:

```
$("#currentList").append("<div class='item'>" + toAdd + </div>);
```

Should be:

```
$("#currentList").append("<div class='item'>" + toAdd + "</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure not to include HTML elements in .js files. (Take `<script> ... </script>` out).
Make sure to have script.js in the same folder directory as your HTML file.

Now in **JavaScript** (script.js):

```
// First line is a short for $(document).ready(function(){ ... });
    $(function() { 
        var availableTags = [
          "ActionScript",
          "AppleScript",
          "Asp",
          "BASIC",
          "C",
          "C++",
          "Clojure",
          "COBOL"
        ];

        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
          source: availableTags
        });

    });
```

In **HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            Autocompleted field: <input id="tags" type="text"  placeholder="Fill me" />
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Pay attention that in the HTML input element we have `id="tags"`, and in JavaScript we use `$("#tags")` to point out to that HTML element.

Now you should be set!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic setup for jQuery UI, http://jsfiddle.net/steelywing/bZP9A/

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="auto.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

auto.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
       source: availableTags
    });
});
```

Comment: Does the order in which I include the "<script src=...>" and "<link ...>" matter? And does it matter if I include them in the <head> or the <body> of the document?

Comment: You can include it in head, just up to you, but `Bootstrap` recommand we include it at end of `body`, but you must include `auto.js` after `jquery.js`

Comment: Log It is still not working but I updated my post with more code to show you what I included in my .html and my .js files.  Do you see what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks

Comment: You need a `=` in `src="script.js"`

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the code I have up there is 100% working and the reason is doesn't work is because of other code I tried to implement.  I wanted to be able to click a button that will add the string in the autocomplete UI to a list on the page, so I tried doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
       source: availableTags
    });

    $("#addButton").click(function() {
        var toAdd = $("input[name=phoneItem]").val();
        $("#currentList").append("<div class='item'>" + toAdd + </div>);
    });
});
```

This not only doesn't work, but it causes the autocomplete and everything else in my .js file to not work either.  Any thoughts as to why this is the case would be helpful, thanks again to everyone!